# What is the correct way to switch between distinct UI hierarchies with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Imagine a typical app that has onboarding, sign-in/registration, and content of some kind. When the app loads you need to make some decision about which view to show. A naive implementation may look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    //assuming some centralized state that keeps track of basic user activity
    @State var applicationState = getApplicationState()

    var body: some View {

        if !applicationState.hasSeenOnboarding {
            return OnBoarding()
        }

        if !applicationState.isSignedIn {
            return Registration()
        }

        return MainContent()
    }
}
```

Obviously this approach fails because SwiftUI views require an opaque return type of `some View`. This can be mitigated (albeit hackishly) using the `AnyView` wrapper type, which provides type erasure and will allow the code below to compile.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    //assuming some centralized state that keeps track of basic user activity
    @State var applicationState = getApplicationState()

    var body: some View {

        if !applicationState.hasSeenOnboarding {
            return AnyView(OnBoarding())
        }

        if !applicationState.isSignedIn {
            return AnyView(Registration())
        }

        return AnyView(MainContent())
    }
}
```

Is there a more correct way of doing this that doesn't require the use of `AnyView`? Is there functionality in the `SceneDelegate` that can handle the transition to a completely distinct view hierarchy?

Comment: You can use ZStack instead of AnyView.

Comment: That does technically work. Is there a better way of handling this situation though?

Comment: `else if` i stead of two separate `if` statements? Honestly? Hard to say - but good question and upvoted. Here's the thing - how long did it take `Swift` to develop best practices? (Has it?) One might call this a poor question because it asks for opinions. Let me give you two. (1) How is this handled in `UIKit`? In `RxSwift`? I have no good answer here. (2) Maybe move as much of your logic into a model or `ObservedObject` that actually *returns* `any View`? I guess it depends on what *you* mean by "is there a better way" with regards to a beta platform that is still rather fragile.

Comment: Thanks @dfd my intuition was that this might have been a case that the SceneDelegate would handle, but I haven't found anything in the src that actually backs up that intuition. Guess I'm just trying to figure out if any of the other early SwiftUI explorers have come across this and solved it more elegantly. I'll try out the Group approach later tonight!

Comment: @superpuccio is one of the good answerers. I used this technique `Group` to either keep an image picker showing full screen or have my "normal" UI displayed - it works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most `SwiftUI`-y way to do things like these is by using the `Group` view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var applicationState = getApplicationState()

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if !applicationState.hasSeenOnboarding {
                OnBoarding()
            } else if !applicationState.isSignedIn {
                Registration()
            } else {
                MainContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The most important thing to note is that, this way, you won't rely on type erasure with `AnyView` (to avoid if not strictly necessary).

If you want to encapsulate the initial view creation in a method don't use type erasure. Instead, use the `some` keyword:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var applicationState = getApplicationState()

    private func initialView() -> some View {
        if !applicationState.hasSeenOnboarding {
            OnBoarding()
        } else if !applicationState.isSignedIn {
            Registration()
        } else {
            MainContent()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        initialView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the way to go at the moment.